# window.opener.document.getElementById("parentId1").value = myvalue not working

Tags: javascript, security, http, https

I was trying to get the value from my child.jsp to my parent.jsp using 
`window.opener.document.getElementById("parentId1").value = myvalue;`

Even though there were no errors found in the console the value is not getting in the parent page.

The child popup window has the url starting like,
`https://safe.cresecure.net/securepayments.....` and the parent page `url` starts with `http://....` is there any issue in communicating with a secure child window and a parent page which is not secure?

If so how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any issue in communicating with a secure child window and a parent page which is not secure?

Yes. HTTP and HTTPS make for separate script origins. (If they were not separate origins then an unprotected page could script into an HTTPS page and change all its content, defeating the purpose of HTTPS.)

> If so how can I solve this issue?

1. Same origin. Serve the parent page through HTTPS, and either put them on the same hostname or set `document.domain` to a shared parent domain on both documents.
2. Cross-origin messaging. `window.postMessage`; if you need to support [older browsers](http://caniuse.com/x-doc-messaging) (primarily IE<8) then there are horrible backwards compatibility hacks (like communicating through `document.cookie` or hash navigation).
3. Server interaction. One document sends the information to the server and the server shares it back with the other document (eg using XMLHttpRequest).